# Does MATLAB MCR contain MCC?

Tags: matlab, docker, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, mcc

I have a script which I need to run remotely using a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) image. For compatibility with another pre-compiled MATLAB application ([SPM](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/)), I need to use a specific MATLAB version in the Docker, and also a different OS. Thing is, I don't have access to this OS / MATLAB version to pre-compile my own script with as well.

So my proposed solution was:

1. download the MCR for the SPM application in the docker image
2. upload SPM (so far this all works)
3. upload the source files of my application to the docker image
4. use mcc to compile my source within the docker image.

My questions:

1. Is this possible? If so: Where do I find mcc within the MCR (since it is not callable as usual)?
2. Better ways of doing this?

Thanks